Cannot find `int_range` function even with the listed features enabled
I cannot compile this code, before submitting an issue I'd like your help to understand if I'm doing it wrong
My main.rs
use polars::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let expr = int_range(0,10,1,DataType::UInt64);
    println!("{:?}", expr);
}

my cargo.toml
[package]
name = "test0"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
polars = { version = "0.44.0", features = ["lazy"] }

according to the docs https://docs.rs/polars/latest/polars/prelude/fn.int_range.html this should compile but I got this error
error[E0425]: cannot find function `int_range` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:4:16
   |
4  |       let expr = int_range(0,10,1,DataType::UInt64);
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^ help: a function with a similar name exists: `date_range`


The function also requires the range feature which is unfortunately not documented.
You can find out by digging through the sources of polars_plan where int_range is defined it contains:

#[cfg(feature = "range")]
mod range;


where range is the module you reach by clicking the Source link on the documentation page you linked
so you'll need to enable range as well:
cargo add polars -F range

or edit your Cargo.toml to include it:
polars = { version = "0.44.0", features = ["lazy", "range"] }

You'll also have to make the first two arguments Exprs which integer literals are not:
    let expr = int_range(lit(0), lit(10), 1, DataType::UInt64);


Since the docs are auto generated this will not be fixed anytime soon see #19496

Thanks @cafce25 your answer is correct and informative
